# error with joomla 4 when i try to get value from user custom Fields

Tags: joomla-4.x

with joomla v3 we use the following code to get values from database

```
//
$userfields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', JFactory::getUser(), true); 
return $customFields[6]->value;
//
```

now with joomla 4 we faced this error Class 'FieldsHelper' not found

Comment: May I ask why you have included `return $customFields[6]->value;`? It seems to be completely unrelated to your question focus.

Comment: Does this fix it? `use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper` at the top of the file as described in [The Forum](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=815&t=988834)?